# Move all files in several folders

Tags: files, directory, zip

So I unzipped a file with 1000+ folders, is there a way to "flatten" these folders? As in, grab all the contents from every folder and dump them into another directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is when you unzip them. If you uncheck the "preserve paths" option (it may have a different name in your zip tool), the folder structure will be ignored during the unzip process, and everything will get put into one folder.

For [**unzip**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/unzip.1.html) this would be the option `-j` to *junk* paths:

```
unzip -j archive.zip
```

Edit: I must share credit for the correct answer with Takkat. The first paragraph was my answer, but the next two lines were Takkat's.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been running a rather complicated set of bash commands (a for loop) for this very thing.

Comment: No need to share credit @Tom. This site is from the community for the community - sometimes its just better to improve an existing good answer than to write another one ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you already unzipped the files (and folders) try this:

First open a terminal, and change directory to the folder where you wish the files to be dropped.

```
cd path_to_folder
```

Then drop this in the same terminal:

```
find PATHtoWHEREtheFILESare -type f -exec mv -iv \{} . \;
```

This will recursively move everything in the *PATHtoWHEREtheFILESare* (you must provide a full path folder's name) into the current folder.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file type of the folder its easy. File type means file extension.

> File extension: jpg, jpeg, png, gif, mp3, ogg, avi, mkv, exe, bin, deb, sh and many more. Its usually last few letter of a file after **.yyy**.

Let assume you have One folder.....

Named **A** which have 1000+ folder and all are full of **.jpg** file.

You can grub all **jpg** at once...for that open folder **A** and click on search (It's up side of the window). Type your file type **.jpg** in the search box and press **Enter** . It will find all jpg from all sub folder. Then you can simply select all file by pressing **Ctrl+a** and **cut/copy**. Paste it where you want to put it.

Comment: I should've been more specific, I'm working solely in the terminal

Comment: Then you need to follow what Tom said.